# Making previous records read only when a new record is created

Tags: related-list, read-only

[image]
I have a related list sitting on my cases called Escalation Tracker.

Each time a new Escalation Tracker record is created, I want to make any previous Escalations read only. Idea is that there should only be one Owner that owns the Escalation, so I am trying to stop people making changes to previous entries.

Comment: One way you could do is have a read only layout and only have one record with status open and rest of all to status closed or some other status. When a new record is created you set its status to open and set the existing 'open' record to closed and assign it a record type whose layout has all fields read only

Comment: i can update this as solution and will you mark this as solution. this may help someone in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Create a read only layout and assign it to a record type with status closed

2.Whenever a new record is created with status open,update the previous record with open status to closed and update it to the closed record type on which all fields will be read-only